# Unable to transform request to binary

Tags: aws-api-gateway

To implement binary support in api-gateway for file upload, i have used `serverless-apigw-binary` plugin and added necessary content types which should be converted by api-gateway.
This is my `serverless.yml`file

```
service: aws-java-gradle

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: java8
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1

custom:
  apigwBinary:
    types:
      - 'application/pdf'

plugins:
  - serverless-apigw-binary

package:
  artifact: build/distributions/hello.zip

functions:
  uploadLoadFiles:
    handler: com.serverless.UploadFileHandler
    role: UploadFileRole
    timeout: 180
    events:
      - http:
          integration: lambda
          path: upload
          method: put
          cors:
            origin: '*'
            headers:
              - Content-Type
              - X-Amz-Date
              - Authorization
              - X-Api-Key
              - X-Amz-Security-Token
              - X-Amz-User-Agent
              - X-Requested-With
            allowCredentials: false
          request:
            passThrough: WHEN_NO_TEMPLATES
            template:
              application/pdf: '{ "operation":"dev-aws-java-gradle", "base64Image": "$input.body", "query": "$input.params("fileName")" }'
          response:
            template: $input.body
            statusCodes:
              400:
                pattern: '.*"httpStatus":400,.*'
                template: ${file(response-template.txt)}
              401:
                pattern: '.*"httpStatus":401,.*'
                template: ${file(response-template.txt)}
              403:
                pattern: '.*"httpStatus":403,.*'
                template: ${file(response-template.txt)}
              500:
                pattern: '.*"httpStatus":500,.*'
                template: ${file(response-template.txt)}
              501:
                pattern: '.*[a-zA-Z].*'
                template: ${file(unknown-error-response-template.txt)}
    environment:
      S3BUCKET: ${env:S3_BUCKET}
      APS_ENV: ${env:APS_ENV}


# you can add CloudFormation resource templates here
resources:
  Resources:
    UploadFileRole:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
        RoleName: "UploadFileRole"
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Service:
                  - lambda.amazonaws.com
              Action: sts:AssumeRole
        Policies:
          - PolicyName: loggingPolicy
            PolicyDocument:
              Version: '2012-10-17'
              Statement:
                - Effect: Allow
                  Action:
                    - logs:CreateLogGroup
                    - logs:CreateLogStream
                    - logs:PutLogEvents
                  Resource:
                    - 'Fn::Join':
                      - ':'
                      -
                        - 'arn:aws:logs'
                        - Ref: 'AWS::Region'
                        - Ref: 'AWS::AccountId'
                        - 'log-group:/aws/lambda/*:*:*'
```

all the necessary settings got implemented in api-gateway after doing `sls deploy`
(checked based on this article https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/binary-support-for-api-integrations-with-amazon-api-gateway/)

but when i hit my end point api gateway is giving out an error like this

```
Verifying Usage Plan for request: 45bac722-f039-11e7-bcc6-f9a1aa509052. API Key: API Stage: fd4ue8lpia/int

 API Key authorized because method 'PUT /upload' does not require API Key. Request will not contribute to throttle or quota limits

 Usage Plan check succeeded for API Key and API Stage fd4ue8lpia/int

 Starting execution for request: 45bac722-f039-11e7-bcc6-f9a1aa509052

 HTTP Method: PUT, Resource Path: /upload

 Method request path:
{}
Method request query string:
{}
 Method request headers: {Accept=*/*, CloudFront-Viewer-Country=IN, postman-token=6f1a23ba-36c2-104d-2e12-dc2c76a985ee, CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto=https, CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer=false, origin=chrome-extension://aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo, CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer=false, User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36, X-Forwarded-Proto=https, CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer=false, Host=fd4ue8lpia.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com, Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate, br, X-Forwarded-Port=443, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=Root=1-5a4c530e-2c1927f85440b71b66cf0c15, Via=2.0 fc18daf68173838631b562fe2efaf8f8.cloudfront.net (CloudFront), x-postman-interceptor-id=8fa8440f-0541-fdac-c60c-6019c2269a66, X-Amz-Cf-Id=P4PYoi5Wwb-NCYRSdTQ_5TdtpbQLBaEATXoyJGC7cS8g6LsoCRPbkg==, X-Forwarded-For=157.50.20.12, 52.46.37.156, content-type=application/pdf, Accept-Language=en-US,en;q=0.9, cache-control=no-cache, CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer=true}

 Method request body before transformations: [Binary Data]

 Execution failed due to configuration error: Unable to transform request

Method completed with status: 500
```

and the request is not crossing api-gateway to lambda function.

But i followed a solution mentioned [here](https://github.com/krisgholson/serverless-thumbnail)
to edit lambda function name in `integration request` section of resource in api-gateway to the same name and click ok. Then error's were gone and working fine.

I checked for changes in roles after doing that but none were found.

Can any one suggest what could have happened there, and any better solutions for the above mentioned problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> But i followed a solution mentioned here to edit lambda function name
>   in integration request section of resource in api-gateway to the same
>   name and click ok. Then error's were gone and working fine.

When you edit lambda function on the console, it sets up the permissions to call the lambda function automatically. If you want to do that manually, you can do that using the [CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html#access-control-resource-based-example-apigateway-invoke-function)

Comment: thanks for response but, 
There were no additional permissions before and after editing lambda function name manually in console.